# Using sed to substitute string in in double quote with a bash variable

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I have a yaml file that I am trying to create a number within a loop and replace it with the newly computed variable.

The line i wish to replace looks like this:

```
 # genesis_gas_limit:            "16000000" ## Used to set genesis gas limit
```

I plan on putting this in a loop and thus I would love it if the sed could take a wild card i.e.

```
 # genesis_gas_limit:            "*" ## Used to set genesis gas limit
```

I have have tried this

```
sed -i 's/ genesis_gas_limit:/c\ genesis_gas_limit: $GASLIMIT' examples/values-local.yaml
```

but i get the following error:

```
sed: 1: "examples/values-local.yaml": invalid command code e
```

I would appreciate any pointers on this

Comment: This might help: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace `genesis_gas_limit:` and whatever content follows it, with `genesis_gas_limit:` and the new value. Using GNU sed:

```
sed -i "s/ genesis_gas_limit:.*/ genesis_gas_limit: \"$GASLIMIT\"/" examples/values-local.yaml
```

Using BSD sed (in OSX):

```
sed -i.bak -e "s/ genesis_gas_limit:.*/ genesis_gas_limit: \"$GASLIMIT\"/" examples/values-local.yaml
```

Comment: Thanks fro your help. From this site i gathered i need to include `""` to the sed command https://ed.gs/2016/01/26/os-x-sed-invalid-command-code/. When i use it with your answer , it doesnt error. however, it doesnt substitute the string in the file. do you . know what might be wrong?

Comment: when i used `sed -e` it does replace the line, but doesnt substitute the variable

Comment: @SamuelDare are you using GNU or BSD version of `sed`? (Look at your `man sed`)

Comment: using an OSX so BSD

Comment: @SamuelDare BSD `sed` has a slightly different syntax for editing files in place. Its `-i` option *requires* a backup extension parameter; if you don't want to make a backup, you must explicitly supply an empty parameter after `-i` (that is, `sed -i ""` instead of just `sed -i`). In your original command, BSD `sed` will interpret the entire `'s/ ...` will be taken as the backup extension, and it'll try to interpret `examples/values-local.yaml` as the `sed` command to execute.